# How to convert PDF to excel using tabula-py into dataframe of several tables?

Tags: pandas, tabula-py

I have a PDF file where are several tables, For example:
[Table from PDF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoN5t.png)

By the way, I learned that I have to use tabula-py from Java (Note: I'm working on Jupyter Notebook
So, I code this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import tabula
from tabula import read_pdf

pdf_path = "..\PDFs\pobreza2.pdf" #File direction

df=tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages="all", stream=True, guess=False, multiple_tables=True) #PDF have many pages with several tables

And I get this:
[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxHia.png)

It's like a list and not a dataframe

So, how could I get this table into a Dataframe? The tables have string and float object